# Simulating/solving a Langevin equation with overdamped dynamics and plotting a phase space plot

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I've been reading about the [Langevin equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation), specifically the case where we are dealing with [overdamped dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation#Recovering_Boltzmann_statistics).

I'd like to simulate the dynamics discussed in the second link and effectively recreate the plots shown in this section (I found these to be quite a helpful visual aid)

[image]

This will allow me to play around with the parameter values and get my head around the concepts.

However I haven't really used Mathematica to solve Stochastic Differential Equations before, so I'm not even sure the best way to start! Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In the [`ItoProcess` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html) under $\to$ Examples $\to$ Applications $\to$ Modeling there is some discussion. Have you looked at that?

Comment: I think that may get me part of the way there, as in it will get you the $x(t)$ data, but I can't see how to get the $v(t)$ to generate the phase space plot I would like -- as shown in my question. But thanks for finding this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(* define process *)
volatility=0.1;
damping=0.05;
spring=1;
{x0,v0}={1,1};
langevin=ItoProcess[{
   \[DifferentialD]x[t] == v[t]*\[DifferentialD]t,
   \[DifferentialD]v[t] == (-damping*v[t]-spring*x[t])*\[DifferentialD]t
                             +volatility*\[DifferentialD]b[t]},
  {x[t],v[t]},
  {{x,v},{x0,v0}},
  t,b \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];

(* simulate *)
tmax=100;
dt=0.005;
SeedRandom[6];
sim=RandomFunction[langevin,{0,tmax,dt}];

(* plot *)
Show[{ParametricPlot[Mean[sim[t]],{t,0,tmax},
                     AxesLabel->{"x","v"},PlotRange->All],
      Graphics[{Red,Disk[{x0,v0},0.05]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is gives me plenty to play with. Let me get to grips with it and I'll give you a green tick.